# Docker /entrypoint.sh: 2: exec: java: not found

Tags: java, docker

I'm using docker to deploy my java springboot application. But everytime I end up with an error

[image]

The dashboard for the docker container is showing the java home

[image]

I'm running the docker file from my InteliJ. Can anyone spot where I am doing wrong ?

**Docker file**

```
FROM openjdk:8u332-jdk-bullseye
RUN addgroup -system useradmin && adduser -system useradmin

COPY ibm-aspera-cli-3.9.1.1401.be67d47-linux-64-release.sh /tmp/ibm-aspera-cli-3.9.1.1401.be67d47-linux-64-release.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/ibm-aspera-cli-3.9.1.1401.be67d47-linux-64-release.sh

#install FFMPEG with global configuration.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ffmpeg

#Installing aspera into the system
RUN sh /tmp/ibm-aspera-cli-3.9.1.1401.be67d47-linux-64-release.sh

USER useradmin:useradmin
#Adding config file to aspera cli
COPY .aspera_cli_conf ~/.aspera/cli/bin
#Adding public key for aspera cli
COPY asperaclient.pem /home/useradmin/.aspera/cli/etc/
#Adding aspera cli into the environment path
ENV PATH="${-}:~/.aspera/cli/bin"
# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} /app.jar
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh


ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev /app.jar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tells you that `PATH` does not contain a binary called `java`.

Try adding `${JAVA_HOME}/bin` to the `PATH` setting.

Comment: Is it like ENV PATH="${-}:~/.aspera/cli/bin:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"

Comment: @PranavMS yes, looks OK to me

Comment: let me try thank you

Answer (score 2):

You use a jdk image so you can override your entrypoint like this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "/app.jar"]
```